# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django

I am trying the tutorial and m stuck on views. 
It says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'"

My project/urls.py says

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
   from django.contrib import admin
   admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In Views.py:

```
def index(request):
request HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

In app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

ultrapatterns = patterns('', 
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

Kind advise is required with some short explanation so I can understand it.

Comment: Is that the *entire* content of your `views.py` file?

Comment: Problem still persists. Now it says "ImportError: cannot import name Views". After I've tried to change 'views to Views in app/urls.py page.

Comment: Can you provide a full traceback?

Comment: Please check the structure of your proyect: existence of _\_init_\_.py files for packages, correct use of package names (is it "polls" right), capitalization on names, and indentation (it doesn't look good in your question).

Comment: yes this is the entire content.

Comment: try to import directly your function index: `from polls.views import index`

Comment: from polls import Views
ImportError: cannot import name Views
[25/Dec/2013 22:43:58] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 96057

Comment: I tried importing function as "views" and "Views" in polls/urls.py but didn't work. Both time it shows "File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 2 in <module> from polls.views import index..."Import Error: No module named views.

Comment: Thanks all for your kind help and problem is resolved. It was a typo. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I got into this state when I didn't save my /polls/views.py file while following the tutorial